# pip: dependency on javascript library

Tags: django, pip, dependency-management

Dependencies to other python libraries can be declared by pip's `requirements.txt`.

But is it possible to declare a dependency to a pure js library?

The library is available from github. The files should be downloaded an made available for django static file handling.

Background: setting up new development environments of a custom django application should be easy.

How do you handle this in your development environment?

Comment: I would write a small management code which checks the existence of the requirements then download them if they don't exists, and put them into either separate python file or `__init__.py` of project top folder or maybe somewhere in `manage.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fanstatic already creates a lot of javascript packages (jquery, bootstrap, ...)

You can use the packages without using fanstatic ...

http://www.fanstatic.org/en/latest/libraries.html

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by [@guettli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/633961/guettli) you can use [fanstatic packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11842444/pip-dependency-on-javascript-library).

E.g. `requirements.txt`

```
django
js.jquery
js.bootstrap
js.underscore
# ...
```

## without django-fanstatic:

Then in your `settings.py` you can have:

```
import js
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    ('js', js.__path__[0]),
)
```

And this is what I have in my base template:

```
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery/resources/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/underscore/resources/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/bootstrap/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

## with django-fanstatic:

[`django-fanstatic`](https://bitbucket.org/fanstatic/django-fanstatic)
 provides a middleware to change the WSGI response. Some more info in [this blog post](http://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2011/04/13/django-lightning-talks.html#django-fanstatic-jan-jaap-driessen-boaz-leskes).

Answer (score 0):

pip install only python packages, so if you want to install a Javascript library, you should create a package that contains only the javascript library (declared as [additional files](http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript#installing-additional-files)).

Not sure if this is really mighty to do this.